# Does $f(x)=1/(1+x^{100})$ have an antiderivative on $(-1,1)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Its clear that $f$ is Riemann integrable, so if an antiderivative were to exist, it would have to agree to this up to a constant. How would I proceed?

Comment: Presumably you are asking how to proceed with integrating $f(x)$?  Is there something you have tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous in $]-1,1[$, it has an anti-derivative there, defined by $$F(x) = \int_{a}^x \frac{1}{1+t^{100}}\,{\rm d}t,$$where $a \in ]-1,1[$.

Recall the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements).

Comment: I agree that this is an anti-derivative, so you have my +1 for simplicity, but I can't help but feel that the heart of the question is in the latter answer, where the thing is actually evaluated.

Comment: When I read it before, it seemed to me that it was a confusion about the function being continous vs. integrable implying the existence of the anti-derivative. I don't know how much editing the question went through later, but since OP accepted the answer, I guess he is satisfied :p

Comment: The reasoning is not quite correct. There are plenty of continuous functions $f$ on $(-1,1)$ for which your formula for an antiderivative is not defined. However, taking the lower limit to be any $a\in (-1,1)$ fixes this.

Comment: @zhw Yeah, you're right. I guess it could blow up in $-1$. I'll fix that

Answer (score 2):

I am puzzled that you would ask.  It is clearly **continuous** on (-1, 1) so certainly integrable there. 
(If the question had been "on (-1, 1]" it would be harder.)

Comment: I think that $0<1/(1+x^{100})\le1$ throughout its natural domain of $\Bbb R$, so I don’t see that endpoints are of any concern here.

Answer (score 2):

This can be written as

$$-\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{\left\{{\omega}:\>{\omega}^{16}-{\omega}^{12}+{\omega}^8-{\omega}^4+1=0\right\}}\frac{\left({\omega}^{12}-2{\omega}^8+3{\omega}^4-4\right)\ln\left(\left|x-{\omega}\right|\right)}{16{\omega}^{15}-12{\omega}^{11}+8{\omega}^7-4{\omega}^3}}{25}-\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{\left\{{\omega}:\>{\omega}^{80}-{\omega}^{60}+{\omega}^{40}-{\omega}^{20}+1=0\right\}}\frac{\left({\omega}^{60}-2{\omega}^{40}+3{\omega}^{20}-4\right)\ln\left(\left|x-{\omega}\right|\right)}{80{\omega}^{79}-60{\omega}^{59}+40{\omega}^{39}-20{\omega}^{19}}}{5}+\dfrac{\frac{\ln\left(\left|x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1\right|\right)}{2^\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{\ln\left(\left|x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1\right|\right)}{2^\frac{5}{2}}+\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2x+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2x-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}}{25}+C$$

Which simplifies to:

$$-\dfrac{2^\frac{5}{2}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{\left\{{\omega}:\>{\omega}^{16}-{\omega}^{12}+{\omega}^8-{\omega}^4+1=0\right\}}\frac{\left({\omega}^{12}-2{\omega}^8+3{\omega}^4-4\right)\ln\left(\left|x-{\omega}\right|\right)}{16{\omega}^{15}-12{\omega}^{11}+8{\omega}^7-4{\omega}^3}\right)+5{\cdot}2^\frac{5}{2}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{\left\{{\omega}:\>{\omega}^{80}-{\omega}^{60}+{\omega}^{40}-{\omega}^{20}+1=0\right\}}\frac{\left({\omega}^{60}-2{\omega}^{40}+3{\omega}^{20}-4\right)\ln\left(\left|x-{\omega}\right|\right)}{80{\omega}^{79}-60{\omega}^{59}+40{\omega}^{39}-20{\omega}^{19}}\right)-\ln\left(\left|x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1\right|\right)+\ln\left(\left|x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1\right|\right)-2\arctan\left(\frac{2x+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-2\arctan\left(\frac{2x-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{25{\cdot}2^\frac{5}{2}}+C$$

Between -1 and 1, this is approximately $1.986299765458299$

Courtesy of http://www.integral-calculator.com

Comment: I like this approach xD

Comment: I was about to say it's hard to believe the antiderivative is so simple, then I realized I didn't check how many terms there are in that sum.

Comment: A few details seem to have been omitted.